# How to send Logs using AWS Log Driver for ASP.net Application

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an `ASP.Net Web Application` and I want to use `AWS Log Driver` to send logs. And I am using `Console.WriteLine` to send the logs. But I don't see any logs in CLoudWatch Logs.

Can I not use `Console.WriteLine` to send logs from ASP.net Application? If not, then how to output logs from Asp.Net application so it can be picked up by AWS Log Driver provided by docker and then sent to Cloud Watch Logs. Or do I need to change something in my `docker file` to get the logs of `Console.WriteLine` to be picked up?

I have set up my Log Configuration in `task.json` file

```
   "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "my-logs", 
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "logs-stream"  
        }
```

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/logging/index/samples/1.x/TodoApiSample

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: My application is not ASP.Net Core, It's Asp.Net MVC application